# Match cell values and compensate for duplicates

Tags: vba, excel

The headline isn´t very good so here is the explanation.

I need to match cell values in column A to column B to find what cell values that are missing from column B.
The problem is that there might be duplicate values. I.e column A has two "Orange" and column B has one "Orange". In this case one "Orange" is missing.

I will write the missing values in, let´s say, column C.

My approach has been to try to create a collection of the valuse form Column A. Run Column B's values against the collection and delete is there is a match. Then write the remaining values in to Column C.

However as you probaly know collection can't handle duplicate values.

I considered using array but deleteing cells from an array seem to be no simple matter form what I have seen.

My limitations is that I can not make any changes to the data I have in the excel file. I.e delete data or add a color to the matched cell etc, this means I can't mark the alreay matched once in a convinient way.

I have no experience with dictionary or if it has any solution to this, but I am not sure that it´s a doable approach since it requires checking a reference.
I don't think copying the data over to a second excel sheet is the right approach either since that might mess upp other stuff going on on the computer.

The question is simply, what alternatives are there? If non I´ll have to make a work-around with the tools I already have. But if there is a way which I have yet not found...

This is the collection approach I wrote.

```
    Sub Test()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim rng As Range

    Dim colec As Collection

    Set colec = New Collection

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet

    Set rng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(5, 1))

     For Each cell In rng.Cells

        If ExistsInCollection(colec, CStr(cell.Value)) = False Then

            On Error Resume Next
            colec.Add cell.Value, CStr(cell.Value) 'Adds the first selected range to collection
            On Error GoTo 0

        Else

            colec.Add cell.Value

        End If

    Next cell

    Set rng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 2), ws.Cells(4, 2))

    For Each cell In rng.Cells

            On Error Resume Next
            colec.Remove (CStr(cell.Value))
            On Error GoTo 0

    Next cell
End Sub
```

This is the function I copied which checks if a value already exists in the collection.

```
'Copied from outside source
Private Function ExistsInCollection(pColl, ByVal pKey As String) As Boolean
    On Error GoTo NoSuchKey
    If VarType(pColl.Item(pKey)) = vbObject Then
         ' force an error condition if key does not exist
    End If
    ExistsInCollection = True
    Exit Function

NoSuchKey:
    ExistsInCollection = False
End Function
```

Please tell me if I have to clarify anything.

I am thankfull for any help you can provide!

/Henrik

Comment: Use a Dictionary instead, with the value as the key and the count in the "value"

Comment: @Henrick - I originally gave an answer using a Dictionary but, after rereading your question and suddenly understanding what you meant by "it requires checking a reference", I added an alternative method using just a user-defined type and a variable sized array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a completely different approach to my other answer, based on the OP's comment that the result is to be written to column C (meaning that column C can be used as a temporary work area):

```
Sub Test()
    Dim lastRow As Integer
    Dim rng As Range
    With ActiveSheet
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("A1:A" & lastRow).Copy Destination:=.Range("C1:C" & lastRow)
        For Each cell In .Range("B1:B" & lastRow)
            Set rng = .Range("C1:C" & lastRow).Find(cell.Value)
            If Not rng Is Nothing Then
                rng.Delete shift:=xlUp
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for both your answers! The part with dictionarys will be usefull to me for other purposes, and the solution with a temporary working area is a splendid idéa which I will capitalize on. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

As Tim Williams said, use a Dictionary.

Below is your code modified to use a Dictionary instead of a Collection (and with some other changes, such as writing the results to column C).

```
Sub Test()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim key As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim r As Integer
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim dictValues As New Dictionary

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet

    With ws
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lastRow, 1))

        For Each cell In rng.Cells
            If dictValues.Exists(CStr(cell.Value)) Then
                dictValues(CStr(cell.Value)) = dictValues(CStr(cell.Value)) + 1
            Else
                dictValues(CStr(cell.Value)) = 1
            End If
        Next cell

        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(lastRow, 2))

        For Each cell In rng.Cells
            If dictValues.Exists(CStr(cell.Value)) Then
                dictValues(CStr(cell.Value)) = dictValues(CStr(cell.Value)) - 1
            End If
        Next cell

        r = 0
        For Each key In dictValues.Keys
            For i = 1 To dictValues(key)
                r = r + 1
                .Cells(r, 3).Value = key
            Next
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

But, if you really, really, really don't want to use a reference to the Scripting object, here is a version without using a Dictionary:

```
Type ValueAndCount
    strValue As String
    intCount As Integer
End Type

Sub Test()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim r As Integer
    Dim p As Integer
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim colec() As ValueAndCount

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet

    ReDim colec(0) As ValueAndCount
    With ws
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lastRow, 1))

        For Each cell In rng.Cells
            p = LocationInCollection(colec, CStr(cell.Value))
            If p = 0 Then
                p = UBound(colec) + 1
                ReDim Preserve colec(p) As ValueAndCount
                colec(p).strValue = CStr(cell.Value)
                colec(p).intCount = 0
            End If
            colec(p).intCount = colec(p).intCount + 1
        Next cell

        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(lastRow, 2))

        For Each cell In rng.Cells
            p = LocationInCollection(colec, CStr(cell.Value))
            If p > 0 Then
                colec(p).intCount = colec(p).intCount - 1
            End If
        Next cell

        r = 0
        For p = 1 To UBound(colec)
            For i = 1 To colec(p).intCount
                r = r + 1
                .Cells(r, 3).Value = colec(p).strValue
            Next
        Next
    End With
End Sub

Private Function LocationInCollection(pColl() As ValueAndCount, ByVal pKey As String) As Integer
    Dim p As Integer
    For p = 1 To UBound(pColl)
        If pColl(p).strValue = pKey Then
            LocationInCollection = p
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
    LocationInCollection = 0
End Function
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help! This last one just might be perfect for my needs in this specific case!